# select statement get time duration

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

let say i have table look like below

```
actionTable
-----------
id, user, actionName, time
1 , userX, startdoing,  1/1/2010 9am
2, userX, endDoing,     2/1/2010 10am
```

may i know whether possible to use 1 sql select statement to   minute record 2 from 1 and get time spent ? or use hibernate.criteria to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this for hours

```
select s.[user], datediff(hh,s.time,e.time) as duration
from actiontable s
join actiontable e on s.[user] = e.[user] and e.actionname = 'enddoing'
where s.actionname = 'startdoing'
```

give me this:

```
user       duration
---------- -----------
userX      745
```

changing to `datediff(minute,s.time,e.time)` gives this

```
user       duration
---------- -----------
userX      44700
```

this will work for an entire table of users and their start and end times if you only have one start and end time for each... if you don't have only one then it gets a little more complicated -- the easy way (with mssql 2005+) is to do something like like this:

```
;with sitems as
(
  select [user], max([time]) as [time]
  from actiontable
  where actionname = 'startdoing'
  group by [user]
), eitems as
(
  select [user], max([time]) as [time]
  from actiontable
  where actionname = 'enddoing'
  group by [user]
)
select s.[user], datediff(minute,s.time,e.time) as duration
from sitems s
join eitems e on s.[user] = e.[user]
```

Comment: If you are using oracle then the last one (containing WITH) will also not work.  You have to use a temporary table.